# Set ag grid readonly fields

Tags: ag-grid

I am using a method per ag-grid example setting

```
  gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [],....etc.
```

and reading a json file from the server that populates the fields (and columns).

// Get data from server   //https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/getting-started/

```
 fetch ('https://dev.perfectiononwheels.com/pricedataJSON/pricelistJson.json')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();

    }).then(function (data) {
        // set the column headers from the data
        const colDefs = gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs();
        colDefs.length=0;
        const keys = Object.keys(data[0])
        keys.forEach(key => colDefs.push({field : key}));

        gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(colDefs);
        // add the data to the grid
        gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);

        });
```

The document states that using this technique you can then set editable:true to be able to edit fields on the grid.  However, I would like to set some columns (fields) as read-only, and change another to a checkbox.

I am not able to find an refernce on how to access a column to change to read-only or a checkbox.
(I was able to set these params when I defined each field in the columnDefs)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct api for this.

To change whether a column is editable, you'll have to change the `editable` property for the column in the columnDefs, and then call the grid api's `setColumnDefs()` method, passing it the updated columnDefs.

Same thing with the `checkboxSelection` property, to show a checkbox or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regular text selection as if the grid were a regular table, set enableCellTextSelection=true and ensureDomOrder=true in the gridOptions.